# how to apply cssClass for ionic2 toast

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2, toast

i followed this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toast/ToastController/) for applying cssClass for my toast.

i have buttons in my html

```
<button ion-button (click)="presentToast()"> toast</button>
```

this my .ts file

```
presentToast() {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "Press again to exit",
      cssClass: "bottomToast",
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    toast.present();
  }
```

this is my app.css file

```
.bottomToast{
    .toast-md .toast-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 40%;
        max-width: 700px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        background: gray;
        /* color: black; */
    }

    .toast-md .toast-message {
        padding: 19px 16px 17px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        /* color: #fff; */
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

my inspect element on the toast i got this

```
<ion-toast role="dialog" class="toast-md bottomToast" aria-labelledby="toast-hdr-0" style="z-index: 19999;"><div class="toast-wrapper toast-bottom" style="transform: translateY(0%);"> <div class="toast-container"> <!--template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Press again to exit" }--><div class="toast-message" ng-reflect-id="toast-hdr-0" id="toast-hdr-0">Press again to exit</div> <!--template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": null }--> </div> </div></ion-toast>
```

When i remove the .bottomToast and give only `.toast-md .toast-wrapper` and `.toast-md .toast-message` it is working fine

> i want the toast css to be inside the `bottomToast` class what i have made worng

Comment: did you check whether the class is applied as parent child or not?

Comment: `<ion-toast role="dialog" class="toast-md bottomToast" aria-labelledby="toast-hdr-0" style="z-index: 19999;"><div class="toast-wrapper toast-bottom" style="transform: translateY(0%);"> <div class="toast-container"> <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Press again to exit"
}--><div class="toast-message" ng-reflect-id="toast-hdr-0" id="toast-hdr-0">Press again to exit</div> <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--> </div> </div></ion-toast>` @suraj this is what i got in my inspect element

Comment: add this to the question please..cant make out in the comments correctly

Comment: please check my updated question @suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bottomToast` is not the parent of `toast-md`. Try :

```
ion-toast.bottomToast.toast-md {
    .toast-wrapper.toast-bottom  {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 40%;
        max-width: 700px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        background: gray;
        /* color: black; */
    }

    .toast-md .toast-message {
    padding: 19px 16px 17px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    /* color: #fff; */
    text-align: center;
}
div#toast-hdr-0 {
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

Comment: i tried the update one and also i tried this one `ion-toast.toast-md.bottomToast` but it is not applyed

Comment: try adding it in the scss page where the toast is called

Comment: Quick fyi: Please watch out with editing posts, and ensure to not approve terrible edits like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42711206/revisions).

Comment: @Seth sure..sry about that.